Declaring parent and child classes in Java
I'm a beginner to Java and I just had a few questions when calling methods from parent and child classes.
Let's say I have a parent class called "Pets" and a child class called "Dog".
What is the difference between these 3 lines?
Dog d = new Dog();
Dog d = new Pets();
Pets p = new Dog();
In short, why do I have to declare a class twice when creating an object and furthermore, in the second line why does d only have the methods from Dog even though Pets is declared? why not just use the first line?
Appreciate your time.
